# 2d vector - find duplicate elements / get index positions and count duplicates

Tags: c++, vector

I have a 2d vector containing lines of text from a file, how can i get the index of duplicate lines and count them.

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < myFileNames.size(); ++i)  
        {  
            infile.open("Whatever\\WhereEver\\" + myFileName[i]);  
        if (!infile.eof())  
        { 
            std::vector < std::vector< std::string>> lines;    
            while (getline(infile, line))  
            {  
                std::vector < std::string> tokens;  
                std::istringstream ls(line);  
                std::string token;

                while (ls >> token)  
                    tokens.push_back(token);  
                if (tokens.size())  
                    lines.emplace_back(std::move(tokens));  
            }  
            for (auto& line : lines)  
            {  
                for (auto& token : line)  
                    std::cout << token << ' ';  
                std::cout << '\n';  
            }       
        }  
        else
        {  
            cout << "Never opened the file line 106 .." << endl;  
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `std::map` with the key as the line vector and an `int` for the value.  As you go through the main vector insert the line vector into the map using `operator[]` and increment the `int`.

```
std::vector < std::vector< std::string>> lines;
std::map<std::vector<std::string>, int> line_counter;

for (const auto & e : lines)
    line_counter[e]++;
```

This will give you count for the number of duplicates for each line.

Comment: Great answer thanks, how do i get the index of matching lines (index[ ]) and the count, when i try to print out i get 11111111112111111112111113111211111411113...etc I can see the count && index positions in there i think, just can't do anything useful in that format